# Update the XML field in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the XML field in one table. I want to update that field. Here is the XML format:

```xml
<data><user>abcd</user></data>
```

I want to change the value `abcd` to `efgh`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please consider first ten entries from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+update+xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples to show how to update to constants, variables or using existing column info:

```
declare @x table(i bigint not null identity(1,1), x xml, y nvarchar(64))
declare @z nvarchar(64) = 'sql variable data'

insert @x select '<data><user>abcd</user></data>', 'sql column data 1'
insert @x select '<data><user>abcd</user></data>', 'sql column data 2'
insert @x select '<data><user>abcd</user></data>', 'sql column data 3'

update @x
set x.modify('replace value of (/data/user/text())[1] with ''efgh''')
where i=1

update @x
set x.modify('replace value of (/data/user/text())[1] with sql:column(''y'')')
where i=2

update @x
set x.modify('replace value of (/data/user/text())[1] with sql:variable(''@z'')')
where i=3

select * from @x
```

Output:

```
i   x                                           y
1   <data><user>efgh</user></data>              sql column data 1
2   <data><user>sql column data 2</user></data> sql column data 2
3   <data><user>sql variable data</user></data> sql column data 3
```

Comment: Check this website, I think their explanation is really concise. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/